# Dynamics 365 Solution which .NET version is used?

Tags: c#, .net, dynamics-crm, microsoft-dynamics, dynamics-crm-webapi

I have a solution for d365 containing plugins written in C#. In these plugins I use the WCF framework for HTTP connections. My initial question was: "Which WCF version am I using?". The result of my research was, that the version is the version of the used .NET framework. So now my question is: When I import my solution to a d365 environment, which .NET version is used by Microsoft, to execute my C# written plugins? Is there a way to see that?

Thanks in advance

Comment: Why are you asking? I'd guess .NET Framework 4.6.2 or later but not .NET (Core) 5 or later. WCF is used to create or call SOAP services, not make HTTP calls. If you use WCF to create a service, you're running on .NET Framework 4.6.2 or later. WCF was never ported to .NET Core (and .NET 5+ are .NET *Core*). The oldest supported .NET Framework is 4.6.2.

Comment: The *why* is important. If you want functionality found in .NET Core you can probably choose a .NET Core deployment environment

Comment: for plugins .NET 4.6.2 is used

Answer (score 1):

For Dataverse (Dynamics 365 CE) plugins you can actually use .NET Frameworks 4.6.2, 4.7 and 4.7.1. For most implementations I use 4.7. It just works fine.

Answer (score 0):

Microsoft recommends the .NET SDK version 4.6.2 developer pack.

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/power-apps/developer/data-platform/org-service/visual-studio-dot-net-framework

> The Microsoft Dataverse SDK assemblies are built using .NET Framework 4.6.2. You can use Visual Studio to build your managed code applications using .NET Framework 4.6.2 or later.

> Plug-ins and custom workflow assemblies should use .NET Framework 4.6.2. While assemblies built using later versions should generally work, if they use any features introduced after 4.6.2 an error will occur.

> When installing .NET Framework 4.6.2 on your development computer, be sure to install the developer pack and not just the run-time. This will enable the 4.6.2 Framework to be chosen in the New Project dialog box of Visual Studio and in the target framework drop-down menu of the project’s properties.